# Find all natural numbers n such that $n+1|n^2+1$

Tags: number-theory

Find all natural numbers n such that $n+1|n^2+1$

I was plugging numbers for n and found that when n is 3 the statement isn't true.

Can someone help me prove the statement.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**

$$n^2+1=(n+1)(n-1)+2$$

How can this be divisible by $n+1$?

Answer (score 4):

Since $n^2 + 1 = (n + 1)^2 - 2n$, this would imply that $n + 1 | 2n$ and that $n + 1 | 2n + 2$, so $n + 1 | 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $n^2+1=(n-1)(n+1)+2$.  If $n+1$ divides $n^2+1$ then it follows that $n+1$ divides $2$, so either $n+1=1$ or $n+1=2$.  Since $n\ge 1$ the only possible $n$ is $n=1$.
Since $n=1$ works, that's the only solution.

Comment: Oops, should have refreshed the page before answering.

Comment: *Almost* right, $n = 1$ does in fact work

Comment: D'oh.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ n\!+\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}n^2\!+1\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^2\!+1\equiv 2$